# Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings

Tags: css, angular, webpack

I have tried solutions proposed for this identical error message without success. When i run my angular project with the angular cli through ng serve, the project runs fine without errors. However, when i compile it with webpack, i get the (full) error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
    at z (vendor.js:1)
    at t.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (vendor.js:1)
    at t.loadDirectiveMetadata (vendor.js:1)
    at vendor.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at vendor.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t._loadModules (vendor.js:1)
    at t._compileModuleAndComponents (vendor.js:1)
    at t.compileModuleAsync (vendor.js:1)
    at e._bootstrapModuleWithZone (vendor.js:1)
    at e.bootstrapModule (vendor.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
    at Object.199 (app.js:1)
    at e (vendor.js:1)
    at window.webpackJsonp (vendor.js:1)
    at app.js:1
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
// Plugins

const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

// Config

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        app: "./src/main.ts",
        vendor: ["./src/vendor.ts", "./src/polyfills.ts"]
    },

    output: {
        publicPath: "",
        path: __dirname + "/dist/",
        filename: "[name].js"
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
      },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [
                    {
                    loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
                    options: { tsconfig: "tsconfig.json" }
                    }, "angular2-template-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                loaders: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ 
            comments: false
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                names: ["app", "vendor"]
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "src/index.tpl.html",
            inject: "body",
            filename: "index.html"
        })
    ]

}
```

.angular-cli.json

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "index": "index.tpl.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts"
    }
  ],
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css"
  }
}
```

app-root / app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { NgFor } from "@angular/common";

@Component ({
    selector: "app-root",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})

export class AppComponent { 

}
```

Any suggestions as to what i am doing wrong?

Comment: can you please share the angular-cli.json file?

Comment: I have updated my post with the code from .angular-cli.json added at the bottom

Comment: show us your component, this error is most likely from your component's styles property

Comment: you probably need to add : styles : [require('yourStylefile.scss').toString()]

Comment: I have added the app-root component. The other components i have follow the same metadata structure.

Comment: Try to add ,"styles": [] in your angular-cli.json like this
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "index": "index.tpl.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts"
    }
  ],
"styles": [],
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css"
  }
}

Comment: I tried both suggestions from the comments, however, i still receive the same error.

Comment: This worked for me. Shall post as answer if it works(sorry about the missing line breaks):

// loader config for angular component styles 
{
  test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
  use: ['raw-loader','sass-loader'], // don't use css-loader for ng2 （unusual）
},
// loader config for global css files
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: [/node_modules/, /src\/app/], 
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
    use: ['css-loader','sass-loader']
  })
},

Comment: Set breakpoint and check which directive raises the error

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions everyone. I solved my issue by following Shobhits'. yurzui, any chance you could link me to a ressource explaining breakpoints? Couldn't find anything useful by googling. Breakpoints sounds like something i need to learn for future debugging.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my issue, by following Shobhit's suggestion, adding the following to webpack.config.json:

```
...
rules: [
{
   test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
   use: ["raw-loader", "sass-loader"]
},
{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   exclude: [/node_modules/, /src\/app/],
   use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
   fallback: "style-loader",
   use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"]
   })
}
...
```

And

```
plugins: [
   new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
...
```

Comment: Using `raw` + `sass` loader for scss files gets rid of the error but also did not load the css properly in my case

Answer (score 0):

This was my webpack setup that worked for scss and css files. For this setup (using Angular Storybook, so this webpack config was located in `./storybook`), I had a global stylesheet in app/styles that needed some extra massaging because it imported other stylesheets in that directory that used relative paths. I also had a custom stylesheet in the same directory as this webpack (`./`):

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postCSSCustomProperties = require('postcss-custom-properties');

const postcssPlugins = () => [
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    autoprefixer({ flexbox: 'no-2009' }),
    postCSSCustomProperties({ warnings: true })
];
module.exports = (baseConfig, env, config) => {
  baseConfig.module.rules = [
    ...baseConfig.module.rules.filter(r => !r.test.toString().includes(".s(c|a)ss")), // base rules supplied by Angular Storybook
    ...
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'raw-loader',
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                plugins: postcssPlugins
            }
        }
      ]
    },
    { // component scss loader
      test: /\.scss$/,
      include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../')],
      exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/styles'), path.resolve(__dirname, './')],
      use: [
        'raw-loader',
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                plugins: postcssPlugins
            }
        },
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    },
    { // global and storybook scss loader
      test: /\.scss$/,
      include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/styles'), path.resolve(__dirname, './')],
      loaders: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'resolve-url-loader', // resolves relative imports
        'sass-loader?sourceMap' // sourcemap = true to assist resolve-url-loader
      ]
    },
    ...
  ];

  baseConfig.resolve.extensions.push(".css", ".scss");
  baseConfig.resolve.alias = {
    ...baseConfig.resolve.alias,
    "assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "../app/assets") // needed to resolve relative paths in imported scss using an alias, where the imported files referred to sheets like "url(~assets/path/to/pic.jpg)"
  }

  return baseConfig;
};
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "@angular/core": "^6.1.3",
   "resolve-url-loader": "^3.0.0",
},
"devDependencies": {
   "@ngtools/webpack": "6.0.8",
   "@storybook/angular": "^4.1.4",
   "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
   "postcss-custom-properties": "^7.0.0",
   "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^3.3.1",
   "postcss-loader": "^2.1.5",
   "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
   "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
   "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
   "webpack": "4.15.0"
}
```